# Portal page with web part - access issue

Tags: web-part, permissions, publishing-site

We have a page which displays some data based on list items which are stored in another site collection. Many of those items have custom permissions set up.

Story goes like this: when user has logged in earlier, when he goes to page with web part, it's displayed correctly. But when he is not logged in and tries to access web part page, he is taken to adfs login page. After successful login, he is taken back to web part page BUT he gets error that he is not allowed to view this page (native sharepoint error). But when he clicks "Go back to site" and tries to re-enter web part page, page is displayed correctly.

We tried with user which is site owner of the other site collection (where list items come from), but issue still exists. Our web application is claims based and we are using ADFS.

I'd be glad for some information where this issue might come from. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should probably run your code with runwithelevatedprivileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx